# Wifi problem on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I have problem with drivers on my laptop. My wifi adapter is **Broadcom BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter**

I am on Ubuntu **14.04 LTS**, and my kernel is : **3.13.0-40-generic**

I was trying three different drivers drivers:

***wl*** - working fine, but not compatible with all routers, so sometimes I cannot connect to wifi network, especialy when wifi network is in *b/g/n* mixed mode or only in *n* mode. So I cannot use "full speed" of internet connection.

***brcmsmac*** - compatible with all routers, I can connect to all wifi networks. But internet connection is totally lagged, sometimes I have to wait more than a minute for loading a webpage. It is not possible to use it. (it is interesting that ping output is good)

***bcma*** - Unable to connect to any wifi network, it doesnt work for me

What do you suggest to me? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read and follow the *very detailed* instructions at [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395) on this site.  This is the best resource on the net for installing Broadcom drivers.

If that helped, flag your own question as a duplicate…